# Aframe React dynamic string value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aframe

Just trying to get my head around using react and aframe together with the spread operator etc.

So I have an Entity using [Meshline](https://github.com/andreasplesch/aframe-meshline-component)

```
<Entity meshline="lineWidth: 20; path: -2 -1 0, 0 -2 0, 2 -1; color: #E20049" />
```

I'm trying to make that path string dynamic with 2 objects i.e. something like

```
buttonConfig.position = {
    x:config.position.x-3,
    y:config.position.y+3,
    z:config.position.z,
}

lineX = {
    lineWidth : 20,
    path: {...config.position,...buttonConfig.position},
    color: '#ffffff',
}
```

But that's obviously not working because I get a

> TypeError: value.split is not a function

How do I turn that object into a string of values via AFRAME/React? Or am I trying to be too clever here and should just build the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the component should be taking object arrays as its input, it seems to always parse the path with its `parse()` function (64th line).

I've tried with [{x,y,z},{x,y,z}], but with no luck.

The workaround is easy though: the `AFRAME.utils.coordinates.stringify` function, which turns an {x,y,z} object into a "x y z" string.

So having an array of coordinate objects, you can get Your coords with one forEach:

```
array.forEach((el, index)=>{
  stringified += AFRAME.utils.coordinates.stringify(el)
  if(index != array.length - 1) {
     stringified +=","
  }
}
```

and use the `stringified` as Your meshline path.

---

It's a bit late, but i've managed to get a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/100672/).